# segmentation fault at clBuildProgram

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, opencl

I'm facing the message of "Segmentation fault" at clBuildProgram when I run my opencl program. There is no error message during compilation this program, but can see the "segmentation fault" when I run it. I summarized Opencl APIs as following. Is there any mistake on my code?

```
clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, &num_platforms);
status = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, &num_devices);
cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
queue = clCreateCommandQueue( context, device, 0, NULL);
cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource( context,1,&str,NULL, NULL);
cl_int result = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I also tried to run as following, but can see the same problem.

```
cl_int result = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

BTW, I'm using the environment of the Linux Ubuntu 10.04 64bit, and NVIDIA GeForce GT 330 for GPGPU.

*EDIT for adding question : The definition of 3rd argument from clBuildProgram is "device list", so I think the "&device" is right. Is it right? If I am wrong, what is the exact meaning of "device list"?

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger, and looked at the variables used to see that they look okay?

Comment: Not yet, because this is the first time for OpenCL programming for me, so I am searching for the debugger that I can use. Do you know any good debugger for solving this problem?

Comment: I would guess that you have a bug in your kernel code. Could you post it here?

Comment: Actually, this opencl code that I am trying to run is from web page for my opencl programming study. You can find the kernel code in here (the codebox at the second on last): http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1241/entry-2254210-realtime-raytracing-with-opencl-ii/

Comment: You can use VS debugger (F5) for host code debugging, for Kernel and API Debugging there is host of programs such as AMD's OpenCL/GL Debugger : http://developer.amd.com/tools/gDEBugger/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to use this AMD's Debugger even though I'm using the system with Intel + Nvidia?

Comment: Is your source string null terminated?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the program using valgrind (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html)? If you will include debug informations also (in g++ or gcc using -g flag) it will show you the actual line of code where the segmentation fault was produced.
Running the program under valgrind is very easy:
  valgrind myprog [arg1] [arg2]

Comment: I'm trying this valgrind by your guidance. I think this is very useful to debug a kind of memory problems. But in my case, there are so many messages from executing this method. I think this is because the kernel code is a little complex.

Comment: You can try running your program under gdb, will produce significantly less output, mostly only your program messages and will break once the segmentation fault is generated. If you compile to include the debug information it will display the line where the fault occurred.

Comment: To run under gdb, you can try: gdb ./your_exe, this will give you a prompt where you can enter the run command. If your program needs arguments, you will set them using 'set args' command before running.